# Prevent cell.backgroundView image from getting squeezed?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm currently setting the backgroundView of my UITableViewCells to images being pulled from eBay's API.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageWithData:imageData] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
[cell setNeedsLayout];
```

The problem is that the table tries to squeeze the image to fit the height of the cell as you can see below:
[image]

What I want it to do is to only show the middle section of the image in the cell, as you can see below. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the Imageview as a backgroung view of cell have to set the content mode of the image before setting to the cell background view:

Try the following code and let me know.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Only thing is that I had to use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` instead of `UIViewContentModeCenter`.

Comment: Ya you can use any of the content mode as per your requirement